# Transfering ETH from Coinbase to Parity, but it does not show up on Parity user

Tags: parity, cpp-ethereum, coinbase, parity-wallet

I tried to transfer 2 eth from a coinbase account to a Parity user (Not wallet). It does not show up on Parity after 5 hours of waiting. 
In Coinbase, it says that the transaction is complete, and on etherscan it says that it is complete, too. The only problem is the Parity user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Parity wallet is not fully synchronized. Balances only show correctly the latest state if the wallet is finished with synchronization.